# Как выводить список уникальный значений в одной строке?

Tags: sql, postgresql, bigquery

Столкнулся с задачей. 
У меня есть запрос:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT carrier) AS operator_count,
COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS device_count,

email,

FROM 
(
  (SELECT crm.carrier AS carrier, crm.device_id AS id, email.md_5 AS email FROM
  `cell-rebel-production.partner_3_indonesia_december.crm` crm
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  `cell-rebel-production.partner_3_indonesia_december.email` email 
  ON crm.device_id = email.device_id)

  UNION ALL 

  (SELECT crm.carrier AS carrier, crm.device_id AS id, email.md_5 AS email FROM
  `cell-rebel-production.partner_3_indonesia_september.crm_v3` crm
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  `cell-rebel-production.partner_3_indonesia_september.email_v2` email 
  ON crm.device_id = email.device_id)

  UNION ALL 

  (SELECT crm.carrier AS carrier, crm.device_id AS id, email.md_5 AS email FROM
  `cell-rebel-production.partner_3_indonesia_february_2020.crm` crm
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  `cell-rebel-production.partner_3_indonesia_february_2020.email` email 
  ON crm.device_id = email.device_id)

)

GROUP BY email
HAVING 
device_count>=1 
-- AND device_count<=6 
AND 
operator_count>=1
ORDER BY device_count DESC
```

Этот запрос выводит таблицу с 3-х колонок. Вот пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т. е. я считаю количество уникальных `carrier` и `id` и группирую их по `email`.
Я хочу в отдельной колонке вывести связь `carrier` - `id`, для каждого `email` т. е. не просто считать количество уникальных значений, а еще и видеть их связь между собою. Как я могу это сделать?

Спасибо

Comment: Покажите пример такого результата - как он должен выглядеть-то?

Comment: @Akina Например, вот так: https://prnt.sc/rrmof9. В колонке CARRIED - ID есть связка по carrier-id для текущего е-мейла. Т. е. если operator_count и device_count у нас 3, то количество таких связок будет 3

Comment: Ну так это вульгарный GROUP_CONCAT(). Правда, есть подвох... *если operator_count и device_count у нас 3, то количество таких связок будет 3* - а вот хрен! девять! каждый из трёх operator_count с каждым из трёх device_count!